# CURL how to call unix error code on http error code

Tags: http, unix, curl

I am calling curl to website, checking what http status code and data if returns.

There are 2 cases:

1. SUCCESS
   website HTTP status code: 200 (OK)
   data: none

needed result: CURL exiting with 0 unix status code

1. FAILURE
   website HTTP status code: 4xx (error) - could be any
   data: text data

needed result: CURL exiting with error status code

For now there is used curl with -f modifier (silent).

```
curl https://mysite.com/something/deploy_status -f
```

It works great, because it checks the HTTP status code, and return unix error code (22) when there is any problem. However, I need to get also to get the text data, that is sent with error code.

How can I do that? Assume that I can make only one curl call, writing a script is not possible there.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Its strictly mentioned in [curl's manual page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-f) `-f Fail silently (no output at all) on HTTP errors (H)`

So make another curl call to save the html separately.

```
curl -o output.html YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE
```

Or use this one that gets you the http status code along with the html page.

```
curl -s -w %{http_code} http://www.example.com/test -o output.html
```